# Wilson loops as representations of the Lorentz group

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, wilson-loop, lattice-gauge-theory

Wilson loops in lattice $4d$ Yang-Mills theory are used to build various glueball states of different spins when they are applied to the vacuum. The spin dependence of such states is related with the particular shapes and orientations of the Wilson plaquettes and are classified according to the representations of the cubic group.

In the continuum a generic Wilson loop is:
$$W(\mathcal{C}) = \mathcal{P}\exp\left(i\oint_\mathcal{C}A\cdot dx\right)$$

I was wondering, and actually couldn't find any reference on this, is there an analog to what happens on the lattice in the continuum? Do Wilson loops form representations of $SO(3)$ when $\mathcal{C}$ is some spatial contour ? (or more generally of the full Lorentz group for space-time paths?). If not, why on the lattice is different?

More broadly, maybe the question that comes to mind both on the lattice and in the continuum is: How does $\mathcal{C}$ affects the spin of states produced by Wilson loops?

If the question doesn't makes much sense I would gladly know why !

Comment: Wilson loops represents the gauge group, not the spacetime isometry.

Comment: Could you elaborate why wilson loops are related with Lorentz group? If it's in Yang-Mills theory, don't they represent the gauge group? When you take a loop in the base manifold, then its lifted in the total space. Then the holonomy should take values in the gauge group. However, its trace is gauge invariant.

Comment: If I could elaborate that would basically answer my question !

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the background to the question. In the continuum we create glueballs by local operators with the appropriate quantum numbers, $F^2\sim E^2-B^2$ for the scalar, $F\tilde{F}\sim E\cdot B$ for the pseudoscalar, $T_{00}\sim E^2+B^2$ for the tensor. These transform as suitable representations of the Lorentz group. What you do on the lattice is approximate these operators by suitable combinations of plaquettes.

Comment: I agree to a certain extenet, but plaquettes are nothing but Wilson loops on small closed paths, how do they get a spin dependance then?

Comment: A small Wilson loop can be expanded in terms of local operators.

Comment: Yes, but which local operators still seems to depend on the shape of the path

Comment: Yes, see Fig.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/9901004

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this paper, that's part of the reason I asked the question

Comment: I think your confusion might be this: On the lattice, I can look at small loops, and they transform according to representations of the hypercubic croup. In the continuum limit, these objects become point-like operators, which transform under the (euclidean) Lorentz group.

Comment: However, imagine you wanted to look at large loops, with a finite area in the continuum limit of order $\Lambda_{QCD}^{-2}$. These corresponds to very large (and increasing as $a\to 0$) representations of the hypercubic group, and classifying them in this way does not seem particularly helpful.

Comment: This is a nice point of view! I think if you could expand a bit on these considerations I would have a nice understanding! What about small loops in the continuum?

Comment: And a large loop in the continuum what does become?